# Parsing json file and count number of items under each object using python

Tags: python, json

I have this json file:

```
"compileFlags": {
    "useVarcharZplitterRemoveIf": false,
    "useVarcharZplitterSortVal": false,
    "useVarcharZplitterSortKey": false,
    "useVarcharZplitterJoinVal": false,
    "useVarcharZplitterJoinKey": true,
},
"runtimeFlags": {
    "useShortcutJoin": true,
    "useMemorySpool": true,
},
"runtimeGlobalFlags": {
    "useMetadataServer": true,
    "metadataServerIp1": 127,

},
"server":{
    "gpu": 0,
    "port": 5000,
}
}
```

I want to be able to count each object inside this json file , for example:
compileFlags=5 (beacuse it got 18 items under its name)
runtimeFlags=2

This is my code:

```
    with open(json_file_path, "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    print(len(data["compileFlags"]))
    print(len[data["runtimeFlags"]])
    print(len[data["runtimeGlobalFlags"]])
    print(len[data["server"]])
read_json_file(path_to_json_file_location)
```

When I am running it I am getting the following error message:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are typo in your code, ``len[data["runtimeFlags"]]`` should be ``len(data["runtimeFlags"])`` and all lines below.

Comment: Oh yeah I missed that thanks! I

Comment: Below is the answer for your question.

Comment: @tupacshakur see my answer, this one you can use to count the elements in any json with your structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below function to return you a dictionary with the count of each element

```
count = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    count[k] = len(v)

print(count)

OUT: {'compileFlags': 5, 'runtimeFlags': 2, 'runtimeGlobalFlags': 2, 'server': 2}
```